# The solution of ODE $k'(x) = r(k(x))$ is infinitely differentiable if $r$ is

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> If there is a function $r(x)$ that is infinitely differentiable, prove that $k(x)$ is also infinitely differentiable if $k'(x) = r(k(x))$ for all $x$.

I am trying to somehow prove using induction. However, after taking many derivatives($1$st, $2$nd, $3$rd order), I have not been able to get to the necessary result.

Comment: How is $r(x)$ relevant to the problem? Did you mean to write that $g(x)$ is infinitely differentiable?

Comment: fixed it with edit...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$f'(x) = g(f(x)) $ where $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is smooth. Show $f$ is smooth.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647213/fx-gfx-where-g-mathbbr-rightarrow-mathbbr-is-smooth-show)

Answer (score 1):

Using the chain rule, can you determine what $k''(x)$ is if it exists?

Can you show that $k''(x)$ necessarily exists based on the assumption that $r$ is smooth and $k'(x)=r(k(x))$ using the chain rule?

Can you show that the $n^{th}$ derivative of $k(x)$, $k^{(n)}(x)$ is a sum of products of

$1)$ $k^{(j)}(x): 0\le j \le n-1.$

$2)$ Derivatives of $r(x)$.

Then, can you use strong induction to show that $k^{(n-1)}(x)$ existing implies $k^{(n)}(x)$ exists?

If so, you are done.

Comment: This was my initial thoughts. However, although I observe that nth derivative is the sum of the products of the derivatives and r(x) and k(x), I haven't been able to prove that that this is true rigorously.

Comment: You could show that by induction if you want. In your proof make a Lemma where you prove the form of the $(n-1)^{th}$ derivative.

Comment: I know in the n-1 case, we assume that it has a sum of such products. But, then how can one use such information to rationalize that the nth derivative satisfies such condition.

Answer (score 0):

**Claim.** For all $n\in\Bbb N$, we have  $$\tag1f^{(n)}(x)=g_n(f(x))$$
where $g_n$ is smooth.

*Proof.*
The claim is true for $n=1$ with $g_1=g$.
Assume $(1)$ holds for some $n$. Since $g_n$ is smooth and $f$ differentiable, we can differentiate the right hand side per chain rule and obtain 
$$f^{(n-1)}(x)=f'(x)g_n'(f(x))=g(f(x))g_n'(f(x)) $$
which is $(1)$ for $n+1$ with $g_{n+1}(x):=g(x)g_n'(x)$, and this is indeed a smooth function because it is the product of two smooth functions. $\square$